# Using a ViewBag with an Extension Method in RAZOR with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4, extension-methods

I'm trudging my way through learning ASP.NET MVC. I've recently written an extension method that helps me decide if a item in a drop down list should be selected. I know about the HTML helper methods. I'm simply trying to learn how things work here. Anyways, I currently have the following code:

```
<select id="Gender">
  <option value="-1" @Html.IsSelected(Convert.ToString(ViewBag.Gender), "-1")>Unspecified</option>
  <option value="0" @Html.IsSelected(Convert.ToString(ViewBag.Gender), "0")>Male</option>
  <option value="1" @Html.IsSelected(Convert.ToString(ViewBag.Gender), "1")>Female</option>
</select>
```

When I execute this, I get a compilation error on the view that says:

```
 CS1973: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' has no applicable method named 'IsSelected' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.
```

My question is, how do I execute an extension method with a value from ViewBag? If I replace ViewBag.Gender with a hard-coded value it works. Which makes me think that the problem is with the fact that ViewBag is a dynamic type. But, what other option do I have?

Comment: Can you post the IsSelected extension? That may help me give you a better suggestion

Answer (score 1):

I'd the same problem.
Use a ViewData instead..
for example, replace

```
 @using (Html.BeginSection(tag:"header", htmlAttributes:@ViewBag.HeaderAttributes)) {}
```

with

```
@using (Html.BeginSection(tag:"header", htmlAttributes:@ViewData["HeaderAttributes"])) {}
```

it works fine ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that may help:

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
    {
public static MvcHtmlString GenderDropDownList(this HtmlHelper html, string name, int selectedValue, object htmlAttributes = null)
        {
            var dictionary = new Dictionary<sbyte, string>
            {
                { -1, "Unspecified" },
                { 0, "Male" },
                { 1, "Female" },
            };

            var selectList = new SelectList(dictionary, "Key", "Value", selectedValue);
            return html.DropDownList(name, selectList, htmlAttributes);
        }

        public static MvcHtmlString GenderDropDownListFor<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, bool?>> expression, object htmlAttributes = null)
        {
            var dictionary = new Dictionary<sbyte, string>
            {
                { -1, "Unspecified" },
                { 0, "Male" },
                { 1, "Female" },
            };

            var selectedValue = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(
                expression, html.ViewData
            ).Model;

            var selectList = new SelectList(dictionary, "Key", "Value", selectedValue);
            return html.DropDownListFor(expression, selectList, htmlAttributes);
        }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
@Html.GenderDropDownList("Gender", 0)
```

or:

```
@Html.GenderDropDownListFor(m => m.Gender)
```